# Cannot inset on mesh properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

im first time making 3D head model an when i try to inset face it makes this weird shape. I think it's because of my scuffed mesh? When i tried doing it on simple cube it works as it should.
And yes i have applied scale. Anyone got a solution?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @RobinBetts worked thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is mirrored, and the edges of your mesh in contact with the mirror-plane are boundaries (i.e. they neighbour only one face).

So in this case, unchecking 'Boundary' in the <kbd>F9</kbd> Adjust Last Operation box, or hitting <kbd>B</kbd> to toggle it, will cause the regions split by the mirror-plane to be treated as if they were single mesh-islands.